# Dynamic Prefix in Symfony4 Controller Route Annotation

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations, symfony4

I want to achieve this annotation in my controller, but i can not find any documentation or a way to have a wildcard(*) prefix in my annotation inside the controller.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/project/*/{Alias}", name="front-story-page" )
     */
    public function ShowStoryFront(Story $story)
    {
      ..
    }
```

I tried a whole bunch of different ways but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you simply tried to add another param ?

```
/**
 * @Route("/project/{WildCardParam}/{Alias}", name="front-story-page" )
 */
```

Comment: I did not know that you can use a param and pass it as just the param in the controller argurements. Thought this was working only with doctrine entities.